# How to remove beginning string in a base64 encoded image?

Tags: javascript, base64

So I got a code for encoding an image to a base64 one..

```
  function toDataUrl(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        callback(reader.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
  }

  toDataUrl('img/no_image_icon.png', function(base64Img) {
    console.log(base64Img); // remove the data:image/png;base64, in the beginning
  });
```

This code works though I want to remove the `data:image/png;base64,` in the beginning of the generated `base64Img`. And also, how can I access it outside of the function? Like example

```
  toDataUrl('img/no_image_icon.png', function(base64Img) {
   var accessOutside = base64Img; // remove the data:image/png;base64, in the beginning
  });

  var newVariable = accessOutside;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323) And why do you want to remove that header?

Comment: @Thomas because at my front end code (angular) I already have that one

Comment: first: if you're already using angular, take a look at [its promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) *(promises in general)*, and the [thread that i've linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323) earlier, that will help you with your async-problem. and 2nd: you say, that you're adding the header in your frontend code? don't do that, that couples these two parts to tight together. So, instead of any URL to any Image, your frontend only works with base64 encoded PNGs. You see how limiting this is?

Comment: @Thomas I can see that. I'm developing an ionic app by the way

Answer (score 3):

Use `String.replace()` method

```js
var base64Img = "data:image/png;base64,AAA=";
base64Img = base64Img.replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
console.log(base64Img);
```

Comment: you can be more generic with what you replace: `/data:.+?,/`

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change the xhr to synchronous request.

```
xhr.open('GET', url, false);
```

and then define `accessOutside` as a global variable.

```
toDataUrl('img/no_image_icon.png', function(base64Img) {
   accessOutside = base64Img; // remove the data:image/png;base64, in the beginning
  });
```

and then you can get the `accessOutside` value from out side.

Comment: I don't know why you need to get the value from out site,  it'd better put your business code in the callback, change the xhr to asyn.

Comment: No, please, don't. That are both bad practices/advices, and will bite you in the ass eventually.

Comment: This is just a way to get the value from out side, it better to change the xhr to asyn and do your things in callback function

Comment: I get an error saying Synchronous requests from a document must not set a response type.